# How to save ActiveRecord object with SCOPED associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a many-tom-many between `User` and `Role`. Here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161022143228) do

  create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "roles_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "role_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "type_of"
    t.index ["role_id"], name: "index_roles_users_on_role_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_roles_users_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

And here is all of my associations:

**Role**

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dev_roles_users, -> { dev }, class_name: 'RolesUser'
  has_many :admin_roles_users, -> { admin }, class_name: 'RolesUser'

  has_many :dev_users, through: :dev_roles_users, class_name: 'User', source: :user
  has_many :admin_users, through: :admin_roles_users, class_name: 'User', source: :user
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dev_roles_users, -> { dev }, class_name: 'RolesUser'
  has_many :admin_roles_users, -> { admin }, class_name: 'RolesUser'

  has_many :dev_roles, through: :dev_roles_users, class_name: 'Role', source: :role
  has_many :admin_roles, through: :admin_roles_users, class_name: 'Role', source: :role
end
```

**RolesUser**

```
class RolesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role

  scope :admin, -> { where(type_of: 'admin') }
  scope :dev, -> { where(type_of: 'dev') }

  enum type_of: ['admin', 'dev']
end
```

---

In a `rails c` I try to do the following:

```
r = Role.create(name: 'super_secret_admin')
u = User.new(name: 'john')
u.admin_roles << r
u.save
```

The last line causes a rollback.

`u.errors` gives `@messages={:dev_roles_users=>["is invalid"]}`

If I save the user first, it works:

```
r = Role.create(name: 'super_secret_admin')
u = User.create(name: 'john')
u.admin_roles << r
u.save
```

---

The crazy thing is that the following set-up makes all the lines of code above work! The user gets saved at the same time with its "pending" associations.

Here is my schema: SAME AS ABOVE

And here is all of my associations:

**Role**

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end
```

In a `rails c` I can now do the following:

```
r = Role.create(name: 'super_secret_admin')
u = User.new(name: 'john')
u.roles << r
u.save
```

Could anybody please explain how to make scoped associations work? I need to create a user with many roles all in the same form.

---

**UPDATE**
Thank you for advice and suggestions on how to design my role architecture. Unfortunately I am not interested in it. The app we are facing this issue in doesn't even have roles. So let me be more clear, the question is:

> How can I assign associations to a user, and then save the user (at the same time with its "pending" associations" if its associations are built using scopes / lambdas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228134/how-to-use-inverse-of-with-multiple-associations?noredirect=1#comment67723540_40228134

Answer (score 0):

I think that an id is needed to assign the roles, when you instantiate the user and assign the roles, that id doesn't exist.

Could you try?

```
u = User.new(name: 'john', roles: [r])
u.save!
```