# How to use :inverse_of with multiple associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

Does anyone know what I should put in the empty fields below to make this relationship work out of the box? I am **very close** to making this work as all associations work flawlessly. The only issue is that I cannot save a user with fruits attached to it as, currently, there is no :inverse_of.

I need the :inverse_of pointing in the right direction so that I can save a user with fruits instead of having to save the user first and then attach fruits to it later.
Thank you!

> UPDATED AFTER COMMENTS:

The **User** model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bought_fruits_users, -> { bought },
    class_name: 'FruitsUser', inverse_of: :buyer
  has_many :bought_fruits, through: :bought_fruits_users,
    class_name: 'Fruit', source: :bought_fruit

  has_many :sold_fruits_users, -> { sold },
    class_name: 'FruitsUser', inverse_of: :seller
  has_many :sold_fruits, through: :sold_fruits_users,
    class_name: 'Fruit', source: :sold_fruit
end
```

The **middle-table** model:

```
class FruitsUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :seller, foreign_key: :user_id,
    class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :sold_fruits_users
  belongs_to :buyer, foreign_key: :user_id,
    class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :bought_fruits_users

  belongs_to :bought_fruit, foreign_key: :fruit_id,
    class_name: 'Fruit', inverse_of: :buying_fruits_users
  belongs_to :sold_fruit, foreign_key: :fruit_id,
    class_name: 'Fruit', inverse_of: :selling_fruits_users

  scope :bought, -> { where(type_of: 'bought') }
  scope :sold, -> { where(type_of: 'sold') }
end
```

The **Fruit** model:

```
class Fruit < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :buying_fruits_users, -> { bought },
    class_name: 'FruitsUser', inverse_of: :bought_fruit
  has_many :buying_users, through: :bought_fruits_users,
    class_name: 'User', source: :buyer

  has_many :selling_fruits_users, -> { sold },
    class_name: 'FruitsUser', inverse_of: :sold_fruit
  has_many :selling_users, through: :sold_fruits_users,
    class_name: 'User', source: :seller
end
```

---

> Still can't save it:

```
u = User.new                    [OK]
u.needs << Fruit.sample         [OK]
u.valid?                        [false]
u.errors                        [:bought_fruits_users=>["is invalid"]]
```

Comment: Hmm... are you sure you can do it that way? Surely Fruits User belongs to two different users -> the one doing the buying and the one doing the selling... in which case you'd want `has_one :seller, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :sold_fruits_users` and `has_one :buyer, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :bought_fruits_users` ? (or add `seller_id` and `buyer_id` and use `belongs_to`)?

Comment: Thanks @TarynEast. I have tried but failed. It still comes up with the same error.. Any idea as to why that might be? This has been bugging me for a few days now! :'(

Comment: I edited the question with the current version! it's much better than before but it still isn't quite working. Still coming up with the same error:
`@messages={:bought_fruits_users=>["is invalid"]}, @details={:bought_fruits_users=>[{:error=>:invalid}]}`

Comment: I don't think you quite got what I was saying... how does rails tell when a `user_id` is for a seller vs for a buyer? You are trying to do two things with a single column.... perhaps you should have two columns? one named `seller_id` and one named `buyer_id` ?

Comment: Hi @TarynEast. Thanks SO MUCH for this. It really is helping understand ActiveRecord way better than ever before. I am going to add an extra column and I am sure I will get this working (thanks to you!) But pardon my silly question, isn't Rails (or shouldn't be Rails) smart enough to tell by looking at the "type_of" attribute? And (personal opinion / completely unrelated) do you like this architecture for when there is a single collection of objects that the User model interfaces with very differently?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question... the type of the column is "user" - but you have two different kinds of user here... and rails doesn't know which one you are asking about, all it knows is it's a user... not whether it's a selling-user or a buying-user... that's what you're distinguishing with the two different columns. Also it means you'll only need one object to represent a single transaction (between buyer, seller and fruits) instead of having to create two (one between buyer-and-fruits, one between seller-and-fruits). so it's a simpler architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand now. I was hoping to be able to have rails distinguish between sellers and buyers based on the extra column that I placed in the middle-table called ":type_of" and use that as a flag setting it to either 0 or 1 depending on whether it's for a seller or buyer. The example works flawlessly e.g. I can do `user.sold_fruits_users` but I can see that the object in the middle table is fine and has the correct :type_of field but I cannot got past that table and go `user.sold_fruits`. I guess you are right. But isn't the :type_of field redundant now I wonder?

Comment: It's the middle-table that has the issue :) But yeah - you could do that (having a transaction-kind column) but you'd need to specify that column in every association where the buyer/seller is relevant... and it's harder to understand than just having a single-transaction model. Yeah, the type_of field would be redundant if you replaced it with buyer_id and seller_id

Comment: Thank you for all your help @TarynEast I will update the question with the final answer soon!

Comment: If you have an answer - feel free to add it as an actual Answer (ie below)... don't just add it to your question. That way if people have the same problem as you, they can see that the question has a working solution that could help them too :)